# Limit of $\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}x$ using l'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, radicals

I'm trying to find
$$\lim_{x\downarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}$$
using l'Hôpital's rule but I seem to be stuck in a loop. I have tried applying l'Hôpital several times but the derivatives always contain the radical and the whole thing ends up being $0\over0$

Is there some way to rewrite $1-\cos x$ or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You might consider $\cos(x)= 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2}+\cdots$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT

I would say: $\quad\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}{x}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}=\cdots$

Comment: @Henry:  Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome - it is a good step but originally had a typo

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

$$1-\cos x=2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}.  $$

Answer (score 4):

Another hint : Multiply the top and the bottom by $\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}$.

Answer (score 3):

You may observe that
$$
\sqrt{1-\cos x}=\sqrt{2\sin^2 (x/2)}=\sqrt{2}\:|\sin(x/2)|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$, so:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{2}\big|\sin\frac{x}{2}\big|}{x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big|\sin\frac{x}{2}\big|}{\frac{x}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: This supposes $x>0$ (which is the O.P.'s hypothesis anyway).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{1-\cos x}=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{1+\cos x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan{\frac{x}{2}}\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Another method is to use the Taylor series expansion